# How to use the ACTUAL string from my SQL query into a subsequent FROM statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use the actual result string from my query into a FROM statement in SQL.

I have such a table where:

```
SELECT Table_Location
FROM foo
```

Would give us:

```
Table_Location
---------------
Database1.Schema1.Table1
Database1.Schema1.Table2
etc..
```

Where Database1.Schema1.Table1 and others are actual tables that can be queried themselves.

I would like to subsequetly extract information from these tables. I was trying to get something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Table_Location FROM foo LIMIT 1)
```

And obtain something like:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
-------------------------------------
a         5         7         10
b         6         2         33
c         2         5         66
b         2         3         44
```

But instead, I obtain:

```
Table_Location
--------------------
Database1.Schema1.Table2
```

Comment: Where is Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 come from?

Comment: would be from SELECT * FROM Database1.Schema1.Table2

My apologies if I didn't explain myself well enough

Comment: What do you want to do from the outer query and inner query?

Comment: I want my inner query to return a table name and my outer query to actually query that specific table. On paper, I could do a join, but my real world example doesn't ideally allow it, so I was instead hoping I could turn my inner query result into a variable to be used by my outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to achieve this in SQL Server. The key steps would be:

1. Select the table locations into a temp table:

```
SELECT Table_Location 
INTO #TempTables
FROM foo
```

2. Declare a variable to hold the dynamic SQL query:

```
DECLARE @dynSQL nvarchar(max)
```

3. Construct the dynamic query by selecting from the temp table and concatenating the table locations:

```
SET @dynSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + 
              STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Table_Location) 
                     FROM #TempTables
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

4. Execute the dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @dynSQL
```

5. Drop the temp table:

```
DROP TABLE #TempTables
```

This will generate a query string dynamically selecting from all the table locations and execute it to return the results in a single result set.

The key is using dynamic SQL to construct and execute the query string dynamically based on the table locations returned from the first query.

Comment: Why do you write an answer for SQL Server when they tag Snowflake as their RDBMS?

Comment: I still appreciate it a lot, I'm new to declaring variables so I feel it's still a nice step in the good direction

Answer (score 0):

Set the result of subquery into a variable

```
SET myVar=(...subquery...)
```

Then use the variable as table name

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE($myVar)
```

Please try and let me know